# access 2007 how to open a form multiple times

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a membership/accounting system that I am building. One particular modal is for entering deposits, and if the user selects dues then they also have to select how many member payments are included with the deposit (5 members have paid their dues). Once the user hits ok I have the code:

```
Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 0
If Me.cmbType = 1 Then
    Do Until Counter = intMembCount
        Counter = Counter + 1
        DoCmd.OpenForm "EnterMemberPayment"
    Loop
End If
```

I am trying to get the EnterMemberPayment Modal to open 5 times (or whatever the user chooses), but it only opens once then continues onto the rest of my code. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after searching and trying sooooo many different ways, I found the answer. You have to set the Open form to this;

DoCmd.OpenForm "EnterMemberPayment", , , , , acDialog

I tried:

DoCmd.OpenForm "EnterMemberPayment", acDialog

But this does not work